# Powershell Idle Timeout

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am using the PST Capture Console from Microsoft to import PSTs into Office 365. I use the following to open a session to Office 365.

$UserCredential = Get-Credential

$Session = -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

This will connect and allow me to start an import and I am able to do small PSTS; however when I try to import large PST files the session times out after 3 hours.

I tried using the -IdleTimeout cmdlet but it is not recongized. More research shows that you need to use the -PSSessionOption to be able to set the timeout to never expire (as I want it to only expire when I force remove it). I cannot figure out how to reconfigure my script to work with the -PSSessionOption.

Answer (score 1):

from [the doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849703(v=wps.620).aspx)

> The session uses the idle timeout that is set in the session options,
>   if any. If none is set (-1), the session uses the value of the
>   IdleTimeoutMs property of the session configuration or the WSMan shell
>   timeout value (WSMan:\\Shell\IdleTimeout), whichever is
>   shortest. If the idle timeout set in the session options exceeds the
>   value of the MaxIdleTimeoutMs property of the session configuration,
>   the command to create a session fails. The IdleTimeoutMs value of the
>   default Microsoft.PowerShell session configuration is 7200000
>   milliseconds (2 hours). Its MaxIdleTimeoutMs value is 2147483647
>   milliseconds (>24 days). The default value of the WSMan shell idle
>   timeout (WSMan:\\Shell\IdleTimeout) is 7200000
>   milliseconds (2 hours).

so you could try to globaly modify timeout for all sessions like that :
`Set-Item -path WSMan:\localhost\Shell\IdleTimeout -Value ''`