# Powershell Crash after couple of hours

Tags: windows, powershell, crash, powershell-4.0

I'm experiencing with weird case with my Powershell script.
I have written a script that's execute an .exe file 
this exe runtime is about 3 hours but constantly crashing after 2 hors (1-2 minutes more or less)

I have break my head try to figure out why the process crashing
eventually I found that the .exe crashing because the powershell crashing.

Here is the process execution command:

```
$Proc = Start-Process -FilePath $ExePath -ArgumentList $Arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$Proc | Wait-Process -Timeout 28800 -ea 0 -ev timeouted
```

After I realized this issue cased by the Powershell I have enabled windows powershell logging and find an error message "the pipeline has been stopped"

[image]

The script need perform more actions after the process ends and get its exit code, that's why I used the -PassThru flag.
I have tried to run it without using the PassThru flag or the Process-Wait command, the result stayed the same (the process crashed after 2 hours but there wasn't log with the message "The pipeline has been stopped")

**Important points:**

1. the .exe file is soured with try;catch blocks with logger but did not logged any thing when crashing- this is not a runtime error in the .exe file
2. When running the .exe independently from the command line its finish successfully after ~3 hours
3. The Powershell script run with Administrator privileges
4. The exe is not casing the crashing due to high CPU/Memory/Disk usage

I will follow up once I will have more updates.

Thanks for all the helpers. 
Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of PowerShell ?

Comment: Hi , I'm using 4.0

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Start-Process cmdlet is good for quick things. But, it leaves a lot to be desired when trying to debug why an exe isn't behaving.

To work around this in your case it might be useful to use .Net objects to redirect and change certain things about your instantiation. I put an example function below that I've used when having trouble debugging exe runs.

```
function Start-Exe
{
    param
    ( [string]$exePath, [string]$args1 )

    $returnVal = $false
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = $exePath
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = $args1
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    $exitCode = $p.ExitCode
    #OutputFile can be some log file, or just use write-host to pump to console
    #$stdout | Add-Content $global:OutputFile
    #$stderr | Add-Content $global:OutputFile

    return $exitCode
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply.  I know that there is noting wrong with the exe execution. the powershell process is crashing (when I run the exe independently everything running smooth and its exit code 0)
I'm trying to figure out why the powershell stop after two hours (constantly) 

thanks , 

shlomy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without using `Wait-Process` and see if it is reproducible.

`Start-Process` with `-Wait` parameter .

or Create it in a Job without `-Wait` and wait for the Job using `Wait-.Job` cmdlet

Comment: Hi , I have already tried it , it look like the exe process is registered in something like the CPU under the Powershell process although the PS process finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom when trying to execute an 8 hour process, it would always die after 2 hours, you need to clear the powershell IdleTimeout.

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345020/5357499)